# javah/JNI : cannot access library

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, processing

First I am sorry in advance for my possible english errors. I'm trying to use JNI to call an C++/OpenCV function (to return a histogram) from my Java application which uses Processing (I work with Kinect for gesture recognition and I want to call the C++ code to compare some histograms in real-time). To do that, I followed partly this tuto : 
ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html

I use Eclipse and Visual Studio 2010, Windows 8 64 bits, JDK 1.8 32 bits.

So I build my class file with javac without problem but when I tried to build my header file with javah I have this error :

```
Error: cannot access processing.core.PApplet 
   class file for processing.core.PApplet not found
```

Please note that my Java program compiles and runs correctly if I don't try to use my javah tool (in this case it crashes when it tries to call the JNI method)

Here are my codes:

**MyProcessingSketch.java**

```
package v2;

//imports

public class MyProcessingSketch extends PApplet {

    //various attributes

    public native static void histo(String inFile, long addr);

    static {
        System.load("C:/Users/Richard/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Test/Debug/Test.dll");
    }

    //various methods, among them setup() and draw()

    public static Mat histogram(String inFile)
    {    
        Mat m=new Mat();
        histo(folder+inFile, m.getNativeObjAddr());
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "v2.MyProcessingSketch" });
    }
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "c:/users/richard/workspace/Kinect/src/v2_MyProcessingSketch.h"

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_v2_MyProcessingSketch_histo (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring inFile, jlong addr) {

    Mat base;

    const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars(inFile, 0);
    base = imread(str, 1 );

    /// Convert to HSV
    cvtColor( base, base, COLOR_BGR2HSV );

    /// Using 50 bins for hue and 60 for saturation
    int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
    int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

    // hue varies from 0 to 179, saturation from 0 to 255
    float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
    float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

    const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

    // Use the o-th and 1-st channels
    int channels[] = { 0, 1 };

    /// Histograms
    Mat hist;

    /// Calculate the histograms for the HSV images
    calcHist( &base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist, hist, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    Mat* mat=(Mat*) addr;   
    mat->create(hist.rows, hist.cols, hist.type());
    memcpy(mat->data, (&hist)->data, mat->step * mat->rows);

}   


int main(){return 0;}
```

**My Eclipse tools**

Javac tool : http://hpics.li/4c612ea

Javah tool + my project explorer : http://hpics.li/1054ea2

Please note that all works in the case of the same C++ code (just by replacing the name and the include) and another Java code without the Processing part, like :

**Test.java**

```
package v2;

//imports

public class Test {

    public native static void histo(String inFile, long addr);

    static {
        System.load("C:/Users/Richard/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Test/Debug/Test.dll");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        Mat m = new Mat();
        Mat m2 = new Mat();
        histo(folder+"front.jpg", m.getNativeObjAddr());
        histo(folder+"up.jpg", m2.getNativeObjAddr());
        System.out.println(Imgproc.compareHist(m, m2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

I don't know why (and it is very irritating), but finally javah builded my header files :

**v2_MyProcessingSketch.h**

```
**/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class v2_MyProcessingSketch */

#ifndef _Included_v2_MyProcessingSketch
#define _Included_v2_MyProcessingSketch
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef v2_MyProcessingSketch_serialVersionUID
#define v2_MyProcessingSketch_serialVersionUID 1i64
/*
 * Class:     v2_MyProcessingSketch
 * Method:    histo
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;J)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_v2_MyProcessingSketch_histo
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**v2_MyProcessingSketch_DisposeHandler.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class v2_MyProcessingSketch_DisposeHandler */

#ifndef _Included_v2_MyProcessingSketch_DisposeHandler
#define _Included_v2_MyProcessingSketch_DisposeHandler
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

But when my program calls the native function I have a new error :

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:v2.MyProcessingSketch.histo(Ljava/lang/String;J)V
```